# vcpkg with MinGW?

Tags: mingw, vcpkg

I love the idea of vcpkg, but I think I'd prefer to stick to MinGW as my compiler.

I can't find any resources on whether or not I can set up (or how to setup) vcpkg so that it compiles packages for MinGW instead of MSVC. Could someone point me in the right direction if this is possible please?

There are a few threads on this but they don't have clear-cut instructions and I'm still learning when it comes to this stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use one of the mingw triplets. `(x64|x86)-mingw-(dynamic|static)`, e.g. `x64-mingw-dynamic`.
For example installing boost:
`./vcpkg install boost --triplet=x64-mingw-dynamic`

Comment: You have to additionally specify `--host-triplet=x64-mingw-dynamic` or export [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68145081/5447906). The same is said at [official vcpkg documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/mingw.md).