# issues with SFML project installed through vcpkg and setting up using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, vcpkg

I'm trying to set up an SFML project (which I installed through vcpkg) with CMake in Visual Studio Code. Can't seem to get any of it working after weeks of trying/watching tutorials.

Project directory:

```
- \build
- \cmake_modules
  - FindSFML.cmake
- CMakeLists.txt
- main.cpp
```

Below is my CMakeLists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
project(demo)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics audio CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

I installed sfml using: `vcpkg install sfml:x64-windows`. I'm aware that for vcpkg we could also use `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE path/to/vcpkg.cmake)` or use the PREFIX_PATH like below but that hasn't changed anything. Also some say setting module path (and having FindSFML.cmake file) is necessary to find SFML but apparently as of recently it isn't necessary anymore? But then again when I don't include that module_path folder it tells me it has trouble finding SFML when I run cmake on the build folder.

At the moment when I run: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"`
it seems to build to my build folder with no issues, this is what it says:

```
-- Found SFML 2.6.0 in C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/sfml
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: 
C:path/to/build
```

but when I run: `mingw32-make` it shows an error on the first line of my main.cpp (which is simply `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`) and says

```
fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\demo.dir\build.make:75: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/src/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

I'm just really confused on how to get it set up and running to output just a simple window.

Comment: You have mixed everything. If `find_package(SFML)` uses the `FindSFML.cmake` script which you put into `cmake_modules/` subdirectory, then it is that script which decides the variables it sets. At the beginning of the script you could read its usage. If `find_package(SFML)` uses the script provided by vspkg, then vspkg should show you the usage when install that package. With additional `CONFIG` option, `find_package` doesn't use `FindSFML.cmake` (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#full-signature)).

Comment: Please, add to the question post the output of CMake when you configure the project. That output contains the information about finding SFML. That information could give a hint about the way `find_package(SFML)` worked in your setup.

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've added the output to my question post of CMake when I run the following in my build folder: cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..

Comment: @Tsyvarev should I let vcpkg handle everything and delete the cmake_modules folder? I heard that newer versions of SFML don't need the FindSFML.cmake file but I haven't gotten far when I don't include it

Comment: The line `Found SFML 2.6.0 in C:/src/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/sfml` means that CMake has found SFML installed in vcpkg via CONFIG file. When you install something in vcpkg, the usage pattern (`find_package` and following commands) should be printed. Alternatively, you could look into the config file (exactly its directory is printed by CMake): at the beginning of the file it could be documentation about its usage. Like that [SFMLConfig.cmake](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/2.6.x/cmake/SFMLConfig.cmake.in).

Comment: Note, that vcpkg triplet `x64-windows` corresponds to the package installation suitable for **Visual Studio**. Package installations suitable for MinGW have triplet `x64-mingw-static` or `x64-mingw-dynamic`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031513/vcpkg-with-mingw.