Linkage error of libpqxx (postgresql) on Windows
I added libpqxx (pqxx) via vcpkg to CMake project, however it's failed while building.
Here is CMake code:
find_package(libpqxx CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(PqDataBase PRIVATE libpqxx::pqxx)

And included header:
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

I tried a lot of alternatives of adding CMake, but no one works.
It might need dynamic linkage, but I have no idea how it does.
Here is error message:
D:\PqDataBase>cmake --build .\build
[2/2] Linking CXX executable PqDataBase.exe
FAILED: PqDataBase.exe
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\c++.exe   CMakeFiles/PqDataBase.dir/PqDataBase.cpp.obj -o PqDataBase.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libPqDataBase.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/pqxx.lib  -lwsock32  -lws2_32  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\PqDataBase\build && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary D:/PqDataBase/build/PqDataBase.exe -installedDir C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/bin -OutVariable out""
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/PqDataBase.dir/PqDataBase.cpp.obj:PqDataBase.cpp:(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4pqxx14argument_errorC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/PqDataBase.dir/PqDataBase.cpp.obj:PqDataBase.cpp:(.text+0x311): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4pqxx8internal18demangle_type_nameB5cxx11EPKc'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/PqDataBase.dir/PqDataBase.cpp.obj:PqDataBase.cpp:(.text+0x345): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4pqxx8internal18demangle_type_nameB5cxx11EPKc'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/PqDataBase.dir/PqDataBase.cpp.obj:PqDataBase.cpp:(.text+0x379): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4pqxx8internal18demangle_type_nameB5cxx11EPKc'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/PqDataBase.dir/PqDataBase.cpp.obj:PqDataBase.cpp:(.text+0x3ad): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4pqxx8internal18demangle_type_nameB5cxx11EPKc'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/PqDataBase.dir/PqDataBase.cpp.obj:PqDataBase.cpp:(.text$_ZN4pqxx14argument_errorD1Ev[_ZN4pqxx14argument_errorD1Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN4pqxx14argument_errorE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


Stack Overflow discourages using images which represent textual information. Instead, copy paste error message directly to the question post, as text. See [ask] and that question on meta.

You used vckg to generate msvc binaries and are now attempting to link that with MinGW. For c based code that has a chance of working for c++ its unlikely to work.

I used the different packages that installed via vcpkg,  they work smoothly with the same environment.

You need to use one of the MinGW triplets and not the msvc ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031513/vcpkg-with-mingw

I tried it, at the moment there is issue of installing of x64-mingw-dynamic packages. Now issue is opened  on github, I will try it.  Thank you.
