Unable to build app using vcpkg and Ninja
I am creating a simple test c++ application which is using spdlog for logging.
I am using vcpkg as package manager and Ninja as generator and cmake.
My package is installed successfully inside my project directory under build folder but i think when the app is gonna be built i get an error which is related to Ninja, i suppose.
Here are my application files :
main.cpp :
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

int main()
{
    spdlog::info("Test log");
}

CmakeLists.txt :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe")

project(TestApp)

find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)

add_executable(TestApp main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TestApp PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)

vcpkg.json :
{
  "dependencies": [
    "spdlog"
  ]
}


This is the command that i am executing :
cmake -G "Ninja" -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="F:/projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"  -Ax64

And after those steps i get this error logs :
-- Running vcpkg install                                 
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Compiler found: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
The following packages will be built and installed:
  * fmt:x64-windows@10.2.1#2
    spdlog:x64-windows@1.14.0
  * vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows@2024-04-18
  * vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows@2022-02-06#1
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Restored 4 package(s) from C:\Users\h\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 229 ms. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/4 vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows@2022-02-06#1...
Elapsed time to handle vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows: 3.73 ms
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows package ABI: b8a712261e9443cd39bae6bd0028a3878a661e9bb28f295ecb0143e2805ca720
Installing 2/4 vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows@2024-04-18...
Elapsed time to handle vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows: 10.1 ms
vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows package ABI: ded1630d48dd1567df273733992025b1a68c3d340c5b7dc5cf54318797eeece7
Installing 3/4 fmt:x64-windows@10.2.1#2...
Elapsed time to handle fmt:x64-windows: 14.5 ms
fmt:x64-windows package ABI: 3607a46075b6242cdccdb9413170961d98be188a2868b3893b2eac2dbdaa1ca7
Installing 4/4 spdlog:x64-windows@1.14.0...
Elapsed time to handle spdlog:x64-windows: 36.6 ms
spdlog:x64-windows package ABI: 97c92ae564489470fbd5fab9bd9589c8ea993d43dfefbf7d4f8d8a536c811224
Total install time: 65.1 ms
The package spdlog provides CMake targets:

    find_package(spdlog CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)

    # Or use the header-only version
    find_package(spdlog CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog_header_only)

-- Running vcpkg install - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  Generator

    Ninja

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

As you can see, my package is installed but i have problem on building (spdlog files are under build directory).
Notice :
I do not have any problem when i use Visual studio 17 2022 as generator.

x64-windows means msvc and not g++. It will use msvc to compile binaries for the msvc compiler which are not compatible with MinGW when building c++ based code.

My advice is to use msys2 to install the current MinGW and use pacman to install all of your dependent libraries from the msys2 repositories.

I have not worked with msys2, yet but i wanna know is not there any simpler way to build my app without it ? my purpose is building my app on windows and i do not want to have any problem when i trasfer my codes on docker and build it with one generetor and i know i have to change myy generator from vs to Ninja or make if i use it. I found vcpkg as really cool package manager but i have still problem when i just use -G Ninja for building.  any simpler way and common to use ?

I say msys2 is by far the easiest way to use MinGW

If you really want to use vcpkg there are triplets specifically designed for MinGW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031513/vcpkg-with-mingw

The title and the issue description are irrelevant to vcpkg.
-Ax64 is not for Ninja, it's for Visual Studio * generators. Either use -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" or whatever or remove -Ax64 from cmake invocation. Since you are using g++, the latter is your option.

Thank you, But, I executed this command : cmake -G "Ninja" -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="F:/projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
and got this error :
The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
F:/projects/cppapps/test/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/spdlog/spdlogConfig.cmake, version: 1.14.0 (64bit)


"C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is a sign of a very old gcc. Use MSYS2 and you even will not need to use vcpkg. BTW that gcc isn't even found Compiler found: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe. So, try the first option.

You know, i am ganna build my application on any target os like win, lnx and mac.
so this is why i am trying to use Ninja for windows (my dev environment) and for linux (server environment like docker) while i am really comfortable with visual studio where you mentioned as first option.
I know if i use Vs as gnerator then i will have errors with make or Ninja on docker so i am trying use Ninja everywhere to solving any problem on development and production. am i right on the way?
