g++.exe: error: /utf-8: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
First:
the development environment:Windows
IDE:vscode
when I use cmake build
#include "fmt/format.h"

int main(int, char **)
{
    fmt::print("Hello,world!\n");
}

error informations:
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
enter image description here
[main] 正在生成文件夹: c:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build 
[build] 正在启动生成
[proc] 执行命令: chcp
[proc] 执行命令: D:\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] D:\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -SC:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++ -BC:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
[build] D:\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\build\CMakeFiles C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
[build] D:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build'
[build] D:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/depend
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build'
[build] D:\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++ C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++ C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\build C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\build C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\build\CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build'
[build] D:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/build
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build'
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/a.cpp.obj
[build] D:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -DFMT_SHARED @CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g /utf-8 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/a.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\a.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\a.cpp.obj -c C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\a.cpp
[build] g++.exe: warning: /utf-8: linker input file unused because linking not done
[build] g++.exe: error: /utf-8: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\build.make:79: CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/a.cpp.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** Deleting file 'CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/a.cpp.obj'
[build] mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build'
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build'
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:93: all] Error 2
[proc] 命令“D:\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --build c:/Users/syk/Desktop/c-c++/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --”已退出，代码为 2
[driver] 生成完毕: 00:00:01.612
[build] 生成已完成，退出代码为 2

My CmakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
add_executable(TestVcpkg a.cpp)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(TestVcpkg PRIVATE fmt::fmt)

when I use gcc 13.1.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 the error happened
but I use visual studio kit ,it don't have error
and I set cmd and powershell is utf-8
I found the google and stackoverflow
I found these place do not communicate the problem

Please [edit] your question to show us your CMakeLists.txt file.

Also note that different compilers have different flags and options. Most options used for MSVC can't be used for GCC or Clang, and the opposite.

/utf-8 looks like something the Microsoft compiler would use

The output shows that you are supplying the argument /utf-8 to g++:
D:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -DFMT_SHARED @CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g /utf-8 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/TestVcpkg.dir/a.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\a.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\TestVcpkg.dir\a.cpp.obj -c C:\Users\syk\Desktop\c-c++\a.cpp
g++ does not know that argument and tries to pass it on to the linking stage as an object file, which fails since there is no such file. Remove /utf-8 from the arguments to g++.

I am sorry I do not know that how can I change the /utf-8,because i used the cmake plugins

@user21947699 Ok, then please update your question and put the CMakeLists.txt file that you use to build the project in it. You may even find /utf-8 in plain text in it, and if so, remove it from all definitions that will be used by g++

I have changed it

@user21947699 If that's truly all in your CMakeLists.txt there is something very wrong.  Does the 4 fmt-*.cmake files (that came with the fmt installation) contain anything about Windows or utf-8? Mine does not so with only that CMakeLists.txt file, it compiles fine. Did you perhaps not get fmt directly from github but via some Microsoft repo? In that case, they may have changed the fmt library so that it only works with their compiler. Also, did you build in the same directory using a different compiler previously?

I use the vcpkg install it

@user21947699 Ok, that may be the reason. So, does the fmt-*.cmake files contain anything about utf-8 or any other MSVC specific things? Perhaps you should just build fmt yourself.

in the fmt-targets.cmake contain  INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:/utf-8>"

My guess would be it's a MSVC vcpkg installation which isn't compatible with mingw

@user21947699 Yes, that's exactly it. That will only work with MSVC. You need a fmt library without such things. I recommend building it yourself.

@user21947699 Glad it helped! You're welcome!

I use the vcpkg install it Did you use the correct triplet for MinGW? Remember that the  x86-windows* and x64-windows* are for msvc and are not supposed to be used for MinGW. MinGW has its own triplets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031513/vcpkg-with-mingw

@user21947699 See the info drecherjm added if you don't want to build it yourself.

I have solved the problem yesterday，Thanks again
